# Updating two objects within setState React Native

Tags: react-native

I am making a login form in which I've added validation, for validation I entered a bool object along with that I have object which will take values from setState and then logins the user..
This is my state:

```
 this.state = {
      email   : '',
      nameValdate:true,
    }
```

And that is where I want to add these two objects in setState but gives me error:

```
validate(email){
if(alph.test(email))
{
  this.setState({email},{
    nameValdate:true,
  })
}

 }
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? Can you please post ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

`this.setState({email: email, nameValdate: true})`
or
`this.setState({email, nameValdate: true})`